# Размер картинок в WebView

Tags: java, android, html, webview, jsoup

Пишу прогу для чтения ранобэ. Начал с сайта ranobelib.ru

Паршу text и title классы, собираю html и открываю в webView. Все работает прекрасно, однако картинки слишком большие. Даже смена юзерагента на мобильный не помогло(очевидно, ведь я не паршу скрипты). Что можно сделать?

Вот для примера глава с картинками https://ranobelib.ru/igrok-kotoryj-vernulsya-spustya-10-000-let/prolog-7/

Answer (score 0):

Починил, добавив в head

```
<style>img{display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 90%;}</style>
```